# Possível problema de permissão

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache, ubuntu

Ao tentando rodar um código de php na minha máquina Ubuntu

```
if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
    echo 'Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
    exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
}
```

Ele está apresentando erro:

Percebo que pode ser erro de permissão ma minha maquina, já tentei seguir este tutorial: 
http://fideloper.com/user-group-permissions-chmod-apache

Mas ao executar segundo comando: `$ chmod go+x /var/www` meu Ubuntu apresenta a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
chmod: alterando permissões de “/var/www”: Operação não permitida
```

Alguma dica do que pode ser?

Comment: Já deu permissão de leitura para todos os diretórios do grupo `www-data`: `sudo chown www-data:www-data -R *`. E depois incluiu seu usuário ao grupo root.www-data  algo como `sudo chown seu_user.www-data ` ?

Comment: para modificar permissões de diretórios do sistema você deve executar o comando como *root*, utilize `sudo chmod ...`

Comment: @IvanFerrer Meu usuário já estava no grupo de www-data, mas não tinha rodado ainda o comando de dar permissão de leitura para todos os diretórios do grupo www-data. Mesmo executando agora, não resolveu.

Comment: @Sanção, sim eu já executo os comandos com o sudo... valeu

Comment: Com `print_r($system_path); die();` o que aparece na página?

Comment: tentou: 'sudo chmod 775 -R /var/www' ? para alterar permissões é preciso entrar com sudo

Comment: Faça `sudo chmod 0755 /var/www`, deve ser o suficiente.

Answer (score -1):

Se fores admin da maquina faz

```
sudo chmod go+x /var/www
```

Vai-te pedir a pw e executa depois.

Comment: Executei este comando, nada, ele continua não conseguindo ter a permissão necessária.